# How to Enable Kotlin Android Extensions by Default in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Why kotlin-android-extensions not enabled by default in this latest version of Android Studio? In fact, as long as i know, i have to manually add the plugin in gradle files. Any workaround so that i can add the plugin and enable it automatically everytime i create new project? Thanks before.

ICYMI, this is the code that needs to be added to enable kotlin-android

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    // add kotlin-android-extensions
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.4.20-M2 JetBrains deprecated Kotlin Android Extensions compiler plugin.

kotlinx.android.synthetic is no longer a recommended practice. Removing in favour of explicit findViewById

Very sad news :(, i hate viewBinding

Answer (score 5):

[In this commit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241) you can see the message:

> Replaced kotlinx synthetic with findViewById
>
> kotlinx.android.synthetic is no longer a recommended practice.
> Removing in favour of explicit findViewById.

It says that it is no longer recommended, but that doesn't mean that you should not use it. They are providing guidelines, but you can choose what to use and what not.

Other alternatives:

1. `findViewById`
2. View Binding

Answer (score 1):

`kotlin-android-extensions` is deprecated, you must use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Android studio 4.1 do not support to import kotlin extension